# apply anonymous function on the index of dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply a   anonymous function (using `.apply()`) like `lambda x: x + 1` on indexes of dataframes (not on the columns) how can I do it?

Comment: You need to give more context in order for people to help you. Try including  the programming language (I think you're using python), any packages you're working with (where does dataframe come from), and a code snippet which shows where you're attempting to add the anonymous function

Comment: `df.index += 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be:

```
df.set_index(df.index + 1)
```

another:

```
df.assign(index=lambda x: x.index+1).set_index('index')
```